# Can upload file getting undefined value in using formData and express. How to solve?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload

(React.js)

```
const formData = new FormData()
        await formData.append('title', data.blogTitle)
        await formData.append('description', data.blogDes)
        await formData.append('file', data.file[0])
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/blog/post', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
               console.og(data)
            })
```

Node.js

```
const blogPost = async (req, res, next) => {
const title= await req.body.title
console.log(title)}
```

I have used body-parser

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

I am getting undefined value. Any idea how to fix it. I have tried axios also nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forget to add on my server

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this lib : https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

this something like this :

```
const blogPost =  (req, re) => {
   const title = req.files.title
   console.log(title)
}
```